# My phone tile is missing.

Tags: windows-10-mobile, tiles, pin-to-start, lumia-650

The phone tile is no longer in the front screen or the app list. where has it gone?  i'm using a 650 lumia on windows 10. this obviously means i cant make calls unless they are in my contacts list.

Comment: one of my friend got the same problem in his 630, he couldnt pin sim2 phone tile. he had to do hard reset. he was on 10586.494 when this problem occurred.

Answer (score 3):

If a tile gets unpinned from the start screen, that doesn't mean its uninstalled from the phone.. It's simply removed from the start menu of the phone.

Follow the following steps to get it back to the start screen:

> 1. Unlock your phone, and whilst on the start screen, swipe from the right of the screen to the left.
> 2. Click on the search field and type in `Phone`.
> 3. Long press on the Phone app icon, and an option to "**Pin to Start**", will show..and, voila, you have the phone app back on your
>      start screen.

[image: Cropped All apps list]

Comment: Kevin said that the tile is no longer available in the apps list. `The phone tile is no longer in the front screen or the app list.` Can an app appear in search results although it is unavailable in the apps list?